# How to iterate children in React using render props

Tags: reactjs

I have this pseudo code for my form. Where I would like to display just fields with canAccess=true.

```
const initialValues = {
  firstName: { canAccess: true, value: 'Mary' },
  surName: { canAccess: false, value: 'Casablanca' }  
}

<Form initialValues={initialValues}>
{props => 
  <>
    <div className="nestedItem">
      <Field name="firstName" />
    </div>
    <Field name="surName" />
  </>
}
</Form>
```

With this code I would like to see rendered just field with firstName.

I know that I can iterate through React.Children.map() but I don't know how to iterate children when using render props.
Also there can be nested elements, so I would like to find specific type of component by name.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Just take the children from the props.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. In Form I did React.Chidlren.map(chidren, x => x) and I've got []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const initialValues = {
  firstName: { canAccess: true, value: 'Mary' },
  surName: { canAccess: false, value: 'Casablanca' }  
}

<Form initialValues={initialValues}>
{props => 
  <>
    {
      Object.keys(props.initialValues).map(k => (
        k.canAccess && <Field name={k} />
      ));
    }
  </>
}
</Form>
```

Edit: Your form can perform some logic and pass back filtered items to your component.

```
getFilteredItems = items => Object.keys(items).reduce((acc, key) => {
  const item = items[key];
  const { canAccess } = item;
  if(!canAccess) return acc;
  return {
    ...acc,
    [key]: item
  }
}, {}));

render() {
  const { initialValues, children } = this.props;
  const filteredItems = this.getFilteredItems(initialValues);
  return children(filteredItems);
}
```

```
<Form initialValues={initialValues}>
  { props => 
    <>
      { 
        Object.keys(props).map(k => <Field name={k} />) 
      }
    </>
</Form>
```

Comment: This is one approach but I don't like it because I will have to do it in every place where I will use Form. I have to do it "inside" <Form /> component.

Comment: Your answer helped me to find solution which I was looking for. I will paste it as a separate answer because here I can't format the code. Thx

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for.

```
const Form = ({initialValues, children}) =>
  props => 
    <Authorized initialValues={initialValues}>
      {typeof children === 'function' ? children(props) : children}
    </Authorized>
```

```
const Authorized = ({initialValues, children}) => {
  // Do check 
  React.Children.map(chidlren, x => { 
  if(x.type === Field ) // && initialValues contains x.props.name
    return x

  return null
  ... })
}
```